# Using bubble sort inside a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, numbers, bubble-sort

```
x = open("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\original.txt", 'r')

mylist = x.read()
length = len(mylist)
for y in range(length):
    for q in range(length-1):
        if mylist[q] > mylist[q+1]:
            mylist[q], mylist[q+1] = mylist[q+1], mylist[q]
            print (mylist)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<pyshell#12>", line 4, in <module>

mylist[q], mylist[q+1] = mylist[q+1], mylist[q]

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Can someone explain this error please, thanks.

Comment: The numbers you read in from your text file are likely of type `str`, not `int` or `float`.

Comment: `x.read()` doesn't produce a list. It reads all the contents of the file into a single string. You probably want `x.readlines()`.

Comment: `mylist` is not a `list` , it's a `string` , maybe you forgot to `split` it out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is equivalent to:

```
string = "Some string"
string[0], string[1], = string[1], string[0]
```

i.e. You're trying to modify the character inside the string.

What you want to do is either
a) Split the contents into a list of words using `mylist.split()`.
b) Use `x.readlines()` to read the file a list of lines, and sort those.
c) Split the entire file into a list of characters with `[x for x in mylist]` and sort the characters,

Then use `''.join(list_of_whatever)` to turn the list back into a string.